# Giving absolute values to ui component - doesn't work for iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have added a text box programatically. My code is as follows:

```
t = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [t setFrame:CGRectMake(55,200,200,50)];

    [self.view addSubview:t];
```

When i run it on the iPhone simulator it works perfectly (the textfield positioned at the exact point that i want), but when i run it on the iPad the positions are not proper. I was thinking that it will auto adjust it self when the screen size increase/decrease. How am i going to correct this ?

note: I am not going to use interface builder or story board.

Comment: is the problem is in the size or the position or both?

Comment: Size and positions. actually both.

Comment: You can use NSLayoutConstraints to automatically adjust positions and sizes of views without having to explicitly set frames for all the various size cases.

Comment: @rdelmar Can you show me some code to demonstrate this ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting *absolute values* work just as expected. That’s why the are called *absolute values*. The problem are flexible/dynamic values.

It will not adjust automatically until you tell it to do so. Here are your options:

1. Manually check for **User Interface Idiom** and set two different values. This is the correct way of detecting iPhone and iPad UI:

   ```
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) ...
   ```

   (Create some function for this.)
2. **Calculate the values** based on screen or superview size:

   ```
   CGSize screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
   frame.size.width = screen.width / 2 - 40;
   ```
3. Set **autoresizing mask**, which set up rules on now subviews are resized, when superview changes size:

   ```
   view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth;
   ```

   Must be combined with some fixed or calculated frame values. Autoresizing is useful only when the view *resizes*, not when you set it for the first time, so this is not exactly your case. For full description of how this works, see `UIView` documentation.
4. Use **Auto Layout**, which is powerful, but quite complex soluton to dynamic layout. At first you would need to read about it and experiment to fully understand how to use it.

If you have a view, whose size and position cannot be described with some kind of rules, you will have to write the coordinates directly (option 1).

Answer (score 0):

Hey mate please use the below code if you are not comfortable using the storyboard or xib file.

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
t = [[UITextField alloc] init];
if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]) // For iPhone
{
    [t setFrame:CGRectMake(55,200,200,50)];
}
else                                       // For iPad
{
    [t setFrame:CGRectMake(55,200,600,100)];
}
[self.view addSubview:t];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: OMG so i have to design the app for both iPhone and iPad. Again iPhone has 3.5' and 4' screens. So that's a lot. Isn't there any other way i could do this ?

Comment: Yes mate either you use the xib file where you are able to adjust the position manually or you would have to put condition at all places.

This is how it works in universal app whether in iOS or android.

Comment: _-1_ For checking device type using string compatison!

Comment: @RavirajJadeja XIBs don’t solve anything. You may end up with two XIBs for every screen, one for iPad, one for iPhone. The real solution, is to design reusable UI, that can be described with _rules_. See my answer.

Comment: When i run it on the iPhone simulator it works perfectly (the textfield positioned at the exact point that i want), but when i run it on the iPad the positions are not proper.

This was stated by you now if your look what you have written it states according to our knowledge that you already have two xib and you need to write every object programmatically. Thats the only reason people over here are posting there answer.

Make sure you describe the question nicely when you ask anything again. Have a nice day ahead mate